# Multiple permutations, including duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, permutation

I have a list of 6 elements `L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` and would like to generate all possible 4 letter combinations - **including duplicate values**.

i.e `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` as well as `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']` and `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']`, etc.

So far I have been using `import itertools: p = list(itertools.permutations(L, 4))`. (Python 2.7.6)

However, this is only giving me the 360 unique combinations, rather than the 1296 that I want.

Thanks!!

Comment: Mathematically speaking, your looking for *permutations*, not *combinations*. The combinations of items in a set are unordered sets of distinct elements (no duplicates).

Answer (score 11):

This is a cartesian product of 4 copies of the list. You want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
itertools.product(L, repeat=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

One can solve this in at least 3 ways.

1. Using nested loop
2. Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
3. Using [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Let's see how to use these and deep into the time performance of these:

```
from time import time

# Solution 1
time_start = time()
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ar = []
for a in L:
    for b in L:
        for c in L:
            for d in L:
                ar.append([a,b,c,d])
print(len(ar))
time_end = time()
print('Nested Iterations took %f seconds' %(time_end-time_start))


# Solution 2
time_start = time()
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ar = [[a,b,c,d] for a in L for b in L for c in L for d in L]
print(len(ar))
time_end = time()
print('List Comprehension took %f seconds' %(time_end-time_start))


# Solution 3
import itertools
time_start = time()
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ar = list(itertools.product(L, repeat = 4))
print(len(ar))
time_end = time()
print('itertools.product took %f seconds' %(time_end-time_start))
```

Output:

```
1296
Nested Iterations took 0.001148 seconds
1296
List Comprehension took 0.000299 seconds
1296
itertools.product took 0.000227 seconds
```

So, comparing the ways we see that `itertools.product()` is simpler and effective than the others.

*N.B.: The code is run in https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/. Performance may vary.*